# Commerce create order when registering a new account

Tags: commerce, rules

I would like to create an order  automatically when a request for a new account is done. So far I have created a rule that triggers on "After saving a new user account". The product, in this case a membership is added to the cart, but I cannot seem how to update the order with the address details of the user ?
I have tried creating a new entity,  Commerce Customer profile, and setting its values but these values are not added to the order? Could it be that the new profile is not "connected" to the order? How should that be done?
Any ideas welcome.

Thanx,

/bo

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the question is unclear but really I need to know what steps to include in the rules to be able to extract the user details, and add these to the created order, and then invoice the user.